# GroupJoin returning Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have this 2 lists list1 and list2 and created this GroupJoin:

List1 is a list of Persons (Id, Name) and list2 is a list of Objects (Id, Car, Date).

PS: list1 contains arround 40 elements and list2 for the moment only one element.

I try to set the maxDate but get the error "Sequence contains no elements"

```
var result = list1.GroupJoin(list2, 
                l1 => l1.Id,
                l2 => l2.Id
                (a, b) => new
                {
                    listA = a,
                    maxDate = b?.Max(m => m.Date).Date ??
                        new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)
                                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the expression `b?.Max`, looks like you are expecting that the variable `b`, which represents the related elements of the inner list will be `null` when there are no matches.

But [GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation explicitly states:

> If there are no correlated elements in `inner` for a given element of `outer`, the sequence of matches for that element will be **empty** but will still appear in the results.

So `b` is never `null` and `Max` throws the exception in question when it is empty.

You can solve it in two ways.

First is to use the nullable overload of `Max` which returns `null` instead of throwing exception on empty sequence:

```
maxDate = b.Max(m => (DateTime?)m.Date.Date) ?? new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)
```

This works well for both `Enumerable` and `Queryable` implementations.

The second way which works only for `Enumerable` is to use a combination of `Select`, `DefaultIfEmpty` and `Max`:

```
maxDate = b.Select(m => m.Date.Date).DefaultIfEmpty(new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)).Max()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and resolution.